# symfony 3: how to add role to specific user

Tags: symfony, roles

It looks pretty simple and I'm a begginer with Symfony, but couldn't figure it out.

I'm using FOSUserBundle, and I'm trying to add a specific role (ROLE_ADMIN) to a specific user (e.g. me), so when the user logs in that role is assigned and he can access certain pages.

I tried putting something like this in the `__construct()` method of my User entity, but it didn't work:

```
if($this->getUsername()=='johndoe') $this->addRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
```

When I log in as that user, the debugging utilities show only the 'ROLE_USER', os it is not working.

Is that a right code? Where should I put it?

**Update:**

There was a silly error that accidentally found. I had created the User entity before isntalling FOSUserBundle, and somehow the user I was trying to promote gave me errors through CLI. Maybe it wasn't properly stored in the database. Once I created a new one and tried again, the command worked as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't add the role during runtime, please add it to the user e.g. with CLI command (or by directly changing it in the database) as written in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/command_line_tools.html#promote-a-user):

```
php bin/console fos:user:promote testuser ROLE_ADMIN
```

If you insist on changing the role during runtime it'd be great to understanding what you're exactly aiming for and why.

Another option would be load the single special user as an in-memory user as written [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded):

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    johndoe:
                        password: somepassword
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
```

Comment: I didn't implement the roles in the database, because I only need to use it with one user, and thought it should be something easy to do. I had tried with the command line, but i receive an error: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]        
  Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given 

So I'm stuck! Thanks for your help

Comment: Then why using role concept at all if you're just adressing one special user?

Comment: updated my answer with another option - I still strongly recommend not to 'configure' your single one user in the code.

Comment: it's a simple project, with just a bunch of pages reserved for a few users. I thought asigning ROLE_ADMIN to those users and adding the @Security comment in the controllers might be a good solution.

Comment: so where are your users configured?

Comment: I am using FOSUserBundle, users are in the database. As this bundle does not include roles management, I'm trying to solve it myself, as simple as posible.

Comment: it does - FOSUserBundle supports role mgmt in the way I initially described. So I showed you two clean ways now, if none is serving you, sorry.

Comment: Thanks LBA, found the origin of the problem (post updated). Once solved, your suggestion worked perfectly.

Comment: @LBA, why shouldn't we add roles during runtime? I have an admin page with a list of users. An admin can add and remove the role `ROLE_ADMIN` for a user at runtime. Te value is saved in the database as `isAdmin`. The next time the user logs in, I check `isAdmin` and add the role `ROLE_ADMIN`. Given my intention, how else would I do this?

Answer (score 7):

In case you can access the database, just update the `roles` column:

```
["ROLE_ADMIN"]
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    $userObject=$this->getUser();
     $username = $userObject->getUsername();
     if($username == 'johndoe')
     {
        $user = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByUsernameOrEmail($username);
        $user->setRoles( array('ROLE_ADMIN') );
        $userManager->updateUser($user, true);
    }
```

Comment: why should he want that?